# nginx + fastcgi error when uploading a file over ~60kb

Tags: perl, nginx, fastcgi

Uploading files smaller than 60kb works without a problem, but when I try to upload a larger file, the browser display this error:

```
An error occurred while reading the request
```

No error in the nginx error logs or any other useful information.

This is my nginx config for this particular script:

```
location ~ \.(pl|cgi)$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    fastcgi_index index.cgi;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

And this is a simple perl script I use instead of my original until I can get this working:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<pre>\n";

foreach $key (sort keys(%ENV)) {
    print "$key = $ENV{$key}<p>";
}
print "</pre>\n";
```

How can I get nginx + fastcgi to work with larger file uploads?

Comment: How large is larger? 200kb? 10mb? What is nginx's client_max_body_size set to? (default is 1m).

Comment: larger can be as little as 70kb. If I go over nginx's client_max_body_size (6m in my case) it'll give a different error.

Comment: ugh, this is the only search result for my problem and it is a post from 10 YEARS ago with NO ANSWERS.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Or at least a solution to the problem. I was using fcgiwrap as a wrapper, and apparently it has issues with larger files. So I switched to a different wrapper ( https://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/perl-fastcgi/centos-5 ) and everything works great now.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question